# Deflection angle of an alpha particle when colliding with a stationary nucleus

Tags: electromagnetism, kinematics, experimental-physics, radiation, interactions

Is it possible to calculate the deflection angle of an alpha particle after colliding with a stationary nucleus with atomic number,Z,without actually knowing Z or for that matter without knowing the identity or anything about it.
And how do particle accelerators measure angle of deflection.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93Marsden_experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you measure the alpha particle scattering off heavy nuclei you can just place particle detectors aroung the scattering location. Maybe a small cylinder of lead for example. Or have your detector on a track. Then you can move the detector aroung from 0 to maybe 180 degrees. Then use a particle accelerator to bombard the sample or use a colimated radioactive sample that emits alpha particles.

This is known as Rutherford Scattering and the scattering cross section can be calculated accurately based on coulomb scattering.

More info can be found at these sites.
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/rutsca.html and

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan–Boltzmann_law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law)

Rutherford scattering was performed by scattering alpha particles off gold nuclei. This is essentially scattering off a coulomb potential unless the alpha particle's energy is enough to actually reach the nucleus.

As far as alpha particle scattering off light nuclei that is a whole different field of study and you can google something like 'alpha particle scattering off light nuclei' You'll find many good sources including some recent works.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a photograph of SLAC End Station A:

[image]

The high energy ($E$) electron beam comes in from the left and strikes a target. Typically cryogenic H$_2$, D$_2$, He, or thin sheets of foils (C, Al, Fe, ...).

The scattered electrons are detected in spectrometers. Here the 1.6 GeV, 20 GeV (decommissioned), and 8 GeV spectrometers (left to right).

When studying, for example,

$$ e^-p \rightarrow e^-X $$

where $X$ is an undetected final state, the scattered electron is detected in the spectrometers.

[image]

The detection package sits inside the concrete (and iron and lead) shielded detector hut (the 8 GeV clam-shell is in the open configuration).

As you can see, especially in the 8 GeV spectrometer, it stares directly at the target region, from a fixed angle ($\theta$). The spectrometers sit on rails, so that $\theta$ can be changed between runs.

A large dipole magnet bends the scattered electron out-of plane, allowing on a small range of momenta ($E'$) to enter the detector. Quadrupole magnets focus the scattered electrons according to momentum and scattering angle so that the lab energy and invariant 4-momentum transfer squared:

$$ \nu= E -E' $$

$$ Q^2 = 4EE'\sin^2{\frac{\theta} 2} $$

can be measured.

With that, the structure of free and bound protons and neutrons can be studied.